# Обязательно ли переопределять метод onPause()?

Tags: android

Обязательно ли переопределять метод onPause() ?

И еще такой вопрос:
Есть действие, выполняющиеся в методе onResume() активити.
Если экран устройства блокируется, срабатывает метод onPause().
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы действие продолжало выполняться, даже когда метод onPause срабатывает?
Или это нужно делать в виде сервиса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Обязательно ли переопределять метод onPause() ?

Нет

> Можно ли сделать так, чтобы действие продолжало выполняться, даже
>   когда метод onPause срабатывает?

Зависит от того, что это за

> действие

.

> действие - запрос на обновление location с помощью LocationManager

Можно, но со временем система убьет вашу Activity, и это действие, естественно, перестание выполняться. Поэтому лучше вынести в сервис.

Comment: действие - запрос на обновление location с помощью LocationManager

Comment: @Александр обновил

Comment: если система убьет активити, в процессах его тоже не будет? (как приложение запущено)
или нет?

Comment: @Александр, что подразумевается под "в процессах"? список недавних приложений?

Comment: да, или в диспетчере задач как "активные"

Comment: @Александр вот уж не знаю, как работает ваш диспетчер задач. Это совершенно не стандартное приложение. Но тем не менее, через определенное время пребывания в фоне, система убьет активити. несмотря на то, будет ли приложение отображаться в вашем диспетчере, или не будет

Comment: ок, как тогда сделать так, чтобы система не сразу убивала активити, когда оно находится в фоне?

Comment: @Александр никак. Она убьет его, когда посчитает нужным. Когда именно - зависит от многих факторов. Если хотите выполнять что-то в фоне, при этом не завися от прихотей системы - делайте сервис.

Comment: ок, я понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Методы обратного вызова жизненного цикла активити, такие как: `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()` и тд. - не какие то поля, обязательные для заполнения, а нечто, вроде маркеров, с помощью которых программисту дается возможность выполнить определенные действия при определенных состояниях приложения.
То есть, при наступлении какого то события, например - создание активити, системой будет вызван метод `onCreate()`, если вы переопределите этот метод, то вместе с кодом, который выполняет система в этом случае вы получаете возможность добавить что то свое, что необходимо сделать вам, когда такое событие наступило.
Если вам нечего добавить к тому, что происходит при этом событии - все просто пройдет без вашего участия, система выполнит те действия, которые необходимы ей для данного события и продолжит работу далее - при этом нет никакой необходимости вообще переопределять такой метод обратного вызова.

Сделать так, чтобы какой то код выполнялся после наступлении события `onPause()` может и можно, хотя я слабо представляю - как. Если активити закрывается\уходит с переднего плана - система ее придушит так или иначе. С другой стороны - где этому коду в принципе выполняться - в самом `onPause()`? Я такими невероятными предположениями даже не озадачивался, чтобы точно знать, что будет, но думаю, что система бросит ANR, так как `onPause()` выполняется в UI-потоке и система не потерпит там каких то задержек.

Суровая правда андроид-разработки такова, что если требуется продолжать какие то действия после ухода активити с переднего плана - эти действия должны выполнятся в сервисе.

Comment: суровая правда, но ладно )спасибо )

Comment: если закрывать приложение, сервис тоже закрывается? или продолжает работать?